# Hibernate HQL createQuery NullPointerException

Tags: hibernate, jpa, nullpointerexception

I can't find out why throw this expression always a NullPointerException:

```
String jpql = "DELETE Trend t WHERE t.owner = :owner AND t.shapeId = :shapeid AND t.security = :security AND t.timeframe = :timeframe";         
int rows = 0;       
try {           
Query q = em.createQuery(jpql, Trend.class); // this line throw the exception
...
```

Other requests successfully executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument is supposed to be the type of the objects that the query will return. But this query doesn't return anything, since it's a delete query.

I don't know why it throws a NullPointerException (it shouldn't), but what's sure is that you should use the `createQuery()` method without a Class argument.

Comment: Thx, but why you shouldn't use the createQuery without Class argument?

Comment: It's worked for me, and I found it without class arg. in the official document too..  http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct